# Unpack DNS Wireformat with Python

Tags: python, dns, unpack

I am trying to unpack binary data I get from my DNS (Unbound).
Format is like that (for example):

> '\x00\x10\x03ns1\x06google\x03com\x00'
>
> '\x00\x16\x00\n\x05aspmx\x01l\x06google\x03com\x00'
>
> '\x00\x1b\x002\x04alt4\x05aspmx\x01l\x06google\x03com\x00'

I am doing this in Python and I have been trying to do that with the unpack method of the struct module.

Yet, I couldn't find a proper way to express the format. Can I have some help on that?

Comment: And your expected output would be ?

Comment: How are you getting this data from Unbound?

Answer (score 0):

The DNS wireformat can (and very often does) contain internal pointers within a packet, which falls well outside what the Python struct module is intended to do. On top of that, every single type of resource record needs to be unpacked according to its own specification.

Parsing wireformat DNS packets is a great way of learning how DNS really works, but if your goal is to actually get something done I would strongly suggest finding a library to do it for you. It's not a difficult task, but it's a lot of work.